# AS3 package does not reflect location

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an fla class referencing 'com.poole.blackjack.game', and a folder path starting at the fla root of 'com\poole\blackjack\game'.

When I compile, I get:
'C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop\Blackjack\com\poole\blackjack\Game\Player.as, Line 1  5001: The name of package 'com.poole.blackjack.game' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop\Blackjack\com\poole\blackjack\Game\Player.as'

I tried changing the reference and folder name to 'Game', but get:
'C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop\Blackjack\com\poole\blackjack\game\Player.as, Line 1  5001: The name of package 'com.poole.blackjack.Game' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop\Blackjack\com\poole\blackjack\game\Player.as'

It's like flash is misinterpreting the filepath, though it has worked up until now. Very annoying!

Comment: Are you compiling with cs6 or flash builder ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your package is using 'game' - lowercase g

And you path in the error message is 'Game' - uppercase G

I'd verify that your folder structure case matches the package case.

your error :

`When I compile, I get: 'C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop\Blackjack\com\poole\blackjack\Game\Player.as`

your package :

`'com.poole.blackjack.game'`

Answer (score 0):

Much later than the post, but we encountered a similar issue. It seems there is a bug with the buildsystem / IDE that if you have a file and a directory with the same name, things might get mixed up.
In our case, in the same directory we had a class called Util and a directory called util, and it didn't compile with the same error.
Our fix was changing the Util class to a different name.